# Надо подcчитать количество определенных слов (ИТ) и (ИТ-Х) в введенной строке

Tags: java, строки

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
    
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Введите строку: ");
        String inputString = scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("!", "");
        int countIT = 0;
        int countIT-X = 0;
        int index = inputString.indexOf("ИТ");
        while (index != -1) {
            countIT++;
            index = inputString.indexOf("ИТ", index + 1);
        }
        index = inputString.indexOf("ИТ-х");
        while (index != -1) {
            countIT-X++;
            index = inputString.indexOf("ИТ-х", index + 1);
        }
        System.out.println("Количество упоминаний ИТ: " + countIT);
        System.out.println("Количество упоминаний ИТ-х: " + countIT-X);
    }
}
```

Comment: ознакомьтесь - [ask]

Comment: У вас какая-то ошибка, проблема? Или вы что-то не понимаете? Или вы хотите, чтобы всё сделали за вас?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, *конкретную проблему или ошибку* и *минимальный* код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример.](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 2):

Первая проблема представленного кода: ошибка компиляции, так как название переменной `countIT-X` содержит недопустимый символ `'-'`, её просто исправить, заменив название переменной на `countITX`.

Вторая проблема в том, что одно искомое слово `"ИТ"` является префиксом второго искомого слова `"ИТ-х"`, и поэтому использование простого поиска индекса для подстроки `String::indexOf` не совсем подходит, так как при подсчёте количество вхождений `"ИТ"` будет также учитывать и вхождения `"ИТ-х"`.
Также здесь будут учитываться не *отдельные* слова, а любые подстроки, то есть, для строки типа `"ИТИТ-х"` значения счётчиков будут `countIT: 2`, `countITX: 1`, что нельзя считать правильным результатом.

Для корректного подсчёта слов следует разбить исходную строку на слова по пробельным символам и символам пунктуации, а затем вычисляя частоты слов (с использованием мапы или отдельных счётчиков).

Вариант с использованием мапы и метода [`Map::merge`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#merge-K-V-java.util.function.BiFunction-) для вычисления частоты:

- создаётся мапа частот искомых слов и заполняется нулями
- исходная строка разбивается на слова при помощи `String::split`, где параметром является регулярное выражение `"[.,;!?\\s]+"`, то есть, разделителями слов являются основные знаки препинания и пробельные символы `\s`.
- для каждого найденного искомого слова инкрементируется значение частоты

```java
public static void countWords(String str, String ... words) {
    Map<String, Integer> countMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (String w : words) countMap.put(w, 0);
    
    for (String word : str.split("[.,;!?\\s]+")) {
        if (countMap.containsKey(word)) {
            countMap.merge(word, 1, Integer::sum);
        }
    }
    
    countMap.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("Количество упоминаний '%s': %d%n", k, v));
}
```

Тест:

```java
countWords("ИТ-ц ИТ-х ИТ-х! ит ит-х; ИТИТ-х! ИТ спИТ", "ИТ", "ИТ-х");
```

```
Количество упоминаний 'ИТ': 1
Количество упоминаний 'ИТ-х': 2
```

---

Более "жёсткое" решение со счётчиками для заранее определённых строк:

```java
public static void countSimple(String str) {
    int countIT = 0;
    int countITX = 0;
    for (String word : str.split("[.,;!?\\s]+")) {
        switch (word) {
            case "ИТ": countIT++; break;
            case "ИТ-х": countITX++; break;
        }
    }
    
    System.out.println("Количество упоминаний ИТ: " + countIT);
    System.out.println("Количество упоминаний ИТ-х: " + countITX);
}
```

Тест (искомые строки не передаются как параметр):

```java
countSimple("ИТ-ц ИТ-х ИТ-х! ит ит-х; ИТИТ-х! ИТ спИТ?");
```